# Message is not being displayed in the called layout in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm doing a chatbot that reads message values from JSON. In a chat generally, messages sent are on the left of the screen and received messages are on the right. However, after running my app, all messages are included on the right.

```
The sent message's layout is: my_message.xml
The received message's layout is: their_message.xml
```

The problem is that all message is being displayed using `my_message` although the if condition used with the trace is showing that one of the messages should be displayed on the left.

Below you can find my code.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String jsonStr = null;
    jsonStr = jsonManagement.loadJSONFromAsset("contacts.json", mContext);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                final String id = c.getString("id");
                String name = c.getString("name");
                String email = c.getString("email");
                String address = c.getString("address");
                String gender = c.getString("gender");

                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                String home = phone.getString("home");
                String office = phone.getString("office");

                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                contact.put("id", id);
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("email", email);
                contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                contactList.add(contact);
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0 ; j < contactList.size() ; j++){
                        Log.e(TAG, "contactList " + contactList.get(j).get("id"));
                        if (contactList.get(j).get("id").equals("c200") ) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "their message " );
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                    R.layout.their_message, new String[]{  "email","mobile"},
                                    new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.message_body});
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "my message ");
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                    R.layout.my_message, new String[]{ "email","mobile"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.message_body, R.id.message_body});
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Couldn't get json from assets.
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
}
```

And below you will find the stack trace:

```
2019-08-22 19:47:42.824 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c200
2019-08-22 19:47:42.825 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: their message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.830 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c201
2019-08-22 19:47:42.830 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.835 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c202
2019-08-22 19:47:42.835 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.836 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c203
2019-08-22 19:47:42.836 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.838 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c204
2019-08-22 19:47:42.838 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.839 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c205
2019-08-22 19:47:42.840 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.841 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c206
2019-08-22 19:47:42.842 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.843 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c207
2019-08-22 19:47:42.843 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.844 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c208
2019-08-22 19:47:42.844 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.845 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c209
2019-08-22 19:47:42.846 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.846 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c2010
2019-08-22 19:47:42.847 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.847 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c2011
2019-08-22 19:47:42.848 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message 
2019-08-22 19:47:42.848 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: contactList c2012
2019-08-22 19:47:42.849 24525-24525/com.abc.jsonTest E/MainActivity: my message
```

How can I make the message with their message show on the left? It is currently showing on the right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                    R.layout.my_message, new String[]{ "email","mobile"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.message_body, R.id.message_body});``` is a adapter that shows all items as the same, you need to extends a ```BaseAdapter``` and create the views for left and right, plus you don't need to create a adapter for every message, just add a message to a previous created one

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation has some problems. You do not have to create an adapter for each item on your list. Instead, you might consider writing a custom adapter that takes the list and while binding the views for each item, set the layout of the item that will be used.

You might consider looking into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911637/3145960) for an idea of how the implementation should work in your case. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will try that @Reaz Murshed

Comment: Great! Let me know if there's any problem.